# Unity uNet Low Level API - which values should I snyc?

Tags: unity, unet

I am using unitys unet low level api: TransportLayer.

I send my own message by converting strings to byte-arrays.

I want a server authoritive setting, so that I can try to implement my own client side prediction.

I am also using unitys physics2d, rigidbodies and so on.
I thought about to move the rigidbodies with it's velocity.

I wonder which values I should send from client to server and backwards, to avoid the rigidbody jittering.

I know that I cannot simply send the clients position to the server, because that will cause the jittering "effect".

Would be nice, if anyone can give me guidance.

Thanks :)